# jQuery Galleria plug-in: Make auto-play?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using this [jQuery plugin](http://kranichs.com/johncarder/gallery2)

It is very nice, but I can't seem to figure out how to get it to auto-play. (automatically transition to the next image at an interval)

Has anyone else gotten this to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#galleria').galleria({
    extend: function() {
        this.play(4000); // will advance every 4th second
    }
});
```

Comment: Where exactly do you put this code?: $('#galleria').galleria({ extend: function() { this.play(4000); // will advance every 4th second } });

Answer (score 0):

Actually the new version of galleria has an option for autoplay. looks like this:
(where `.test` is the name of the div layer containing your images)

```
<script>
    // Load theme
    Galleria.loadTheme('../src/themes/classic/galleria.classic.js');

    $('.test').galleria({
      autoplay: 1000
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score -1):

In my experience, it doesn't have that option.  You'd have to hack it to add that.

You might want to consider using another slider plugin: [Easy Slider](http://cssglobe.com/post/4004/easy-slider-15-the-easiest-jquery-plugin-for-sliding), [Galleriffic](http://www.twospy.com/galleriffic/), [Pikachoose](http://pikachoose.com/)